# Passing promise value to headers

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to pass the promise value in headers but am not able to do so.

```
class test{

  constructor(auth_key,auth_secret){
    this.auth_key = auth_key;
    this.auth_secret = auth_secret;
    console.log("============In class test============");
    this.authtoken = this.init().then(function(value){
        return value;
    });
  }

  init(){
    console.log("============In init function============"+this.auth_key);
    let postData = {};
    return this.requestStt('test','POST',postData).then((response) => {
        if (response.status == 200) {
            return response.body.then((response) => {
                //console.log(response.token);
                let apiResp = {stt_token:response.token}
                return apiResp;
             });
        }else {
            console.log(response)
        }
    });
  }

  gettoken(){
    console.log(this.authtoken)
    var reqHeaders = new Headers({
      "Accept":"application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "token":this.authtoken,
      });
  }
}
```

Getting error because `this.authtoken` is a promise object.

Can anyone please help me out.

Comment: as it stands `gettoken` does nothing but create `reqHeaders` - which is then discarded, at the end of the function - to help, how is `gettoken` function used?

Comment: I will use gettoken to hit api's via fetch() that need to pass headers

Comment: so the code to hit api's will be in gettoken? - because, as I said, even as it stands, if authtoken was "ok", that function doesn't return anything

Comment: Okay.. thanks for the reply guys.

Answer (score 1):

if you rewrite gettoken like follows:

```
gettoken(){
    return this.authtoken.then(function(token) {
      return new Headers({
        "Accept":"application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        "token":token,
      });
   })
}
```

then of course, to use those headers, you would need to do something like

```
xxx.gettoken().then(function(headers) {
    // whatever you do with headers goes here
});
```